# How do I prevent a div, which is created by clicking on a button, from disappearing when reloading the page?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I'm using a button to slide down a div which contains a registration form but after I reload the page (or submit the form), the div vanishes and I have to click on the button again. I want the div to stay after reloading the page. Any suggestions?

Here is my jquery code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("button#button_register").click(function(){
            $("#register").slideDown('slow');
        });
    });
    </script>
```

And the button:

```
<button id="button_register">Register! </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to somehow save the state of your `#register` element. You can use server side for this (session) or a simple cookie.

But handling cookies in pure JS is a little bit tricky. Assuming you can use this great plugin: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie you could do something like this:

```
$("button#button_register").click(function(){
    if($("#register")is(':visible')) {
        $("#register").slideUp('slow');
        $.cookie('registerState', 0);
    } else {
        $("#register").slideDown('slow');
        $.cookie('registerState', 1);
    }   
});
```

... than you need to check for this state every time the page is loaded, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($.cookie('registerState') == 1) { 
        $("#register").show(); // or slide down if you want to show an animation every time
    }
});
```